SQL Server 2019 failure due to transaction log is full
The transaction log in our SQL Server log grew to the maximum size of 2 TB, even though the disk is 10 TB.
The server is now generating 9002 errors.
We tried to add another log file, however it failed due to the database is read only.
We are also unable to backup the log for the same reason, and are assuming that the data in the log is lost.
What can be done in this situation?

Have you followed the instructions to recover from the failure? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/troubleshoot-a-full-transaction-log-sql-server-error-9002
